# A question about a Gaussian-perturbed probability distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption, multivariate-normal-distribution

In a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.05600.pdf) I've been reading recently, at some point the authors define a new probability distribution over original data $\mathcal{D} =\{\textbf{x}_1, \dots, \textbf{x}_N\}$, by introducing a *gaussian perturbation*.

In practice, given that we have some (unknown) probability $p_{data}(\textbf{x})$ and some scalar $\sigma >1$, the new (perturbed) probability is defined as

$$q_{\sigma}(\textbf{x}) = \int p_{data}(\textbf{t}) \mathcal{N}(\textbf{x} | \textbf{t} \, ,\sigma^2I) \, d\textbf{t} \, \, .$$

Based on this notation, what I understand is that, if my initial data point is distributed according to the original probability $p_{data}$, what we do now is considering $\tilde{\textbf{x}} = \textbf{x} \cdot \varepsilon$  where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(\textbf{t}, \sigma^2I)$ and therefore the new density function takes into account the introduced noise. Nevertheless, it's not clear what the role of $\textbf{t}$ is in this context and why we integrate over it. Additionally, how can we ensure that the new defined distribution $q_\sigma(\textbf{x})$ integrates to $1$?

Comment: I believe you might be misreading the notation.  This distribution adds an independent Normal "noise" variable of variance $\sigma^2$ to each data value.  This is identical to a Kernel Density estimate using a Gaussian kernel of bandwidth $\sigma.$

Comment: Cross posted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544243/a-question-about-a-gaussian-perturbed-probability-distribution voting to close this one instead.